# Smali code vs Java source code when reverse engineering an android app

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, smali

I'm just looking at android reverse engineering tutorials and I notice that most of them are modifying the smali code instead of the actual java source code after apk has been decompiled, is there a reason for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, what you get from decompiling is *not* complete/correct/compilable Java source.

It's just a [hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) problem to infer (Java) sourcecode from bytecode. Also, certain information from the sourcecode may just be missing from the compiled form, e.g. names of local variables or parameters, so there's no way to restore them through decompiling.

In comparison, translating byte codes to low level (smali) instructions (and vice versa) is trivial.